# PostgreSQL combining tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am a little confused about merging one table into another. My two tables looks like so:

```
Table A                                         Table B
id | name | likes | email | username            id | name | email   | username
1  | joe  |  3    |  null | null                1  | ben  | a@co.co | user


Result: Table A
id | name | likes | email   | username
1  | joe  | 3     | null    | null
2  | ben  | null  | a@co.co | user
```

My issue is that I do not want to overwrite the properties that are in the Table A. Is this a simple `UNION`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just execute `INSERT INTO..SELECT` statement,

```
INSERT INTO TableA(id, name, likes, email, username)
SELECT id, name, NULL AS likes, email, username
FROM TableB
```

What it does is it copies all records from `TableB` into `TableA`. But if you want the records for projection only, then a simple `UNION` will do just fine

```
SELECT id, name, likes, email, username FROM tableA
UNION
SELECT id, name, NULL AS likes, email, username FROM TableB
```

Comment: Okay that looks like what I was trying to write originally but what is going on with the `SELECT id, name NULL AS ...`?

Comment: it sets `NULL` value for `LIKES`. You can alternatively do this, `INSERT INTO TableA(id, name, email, username)
SELECT id, name, email, username
FROM TableB`

Comment: Okay so whatever values I do not want to insert I can leave them out of the columns of the initial `INSERT INTO` statement?

Comment: yes, if you leave them out, the values for that column will be set as `NULL` `:D`

Comment: Thanks for your help and quick response!